# Translating from Fortran to Python a Fourier transform

Tags: python

I was trying to solve a Fourier transform integration in python.The code should do this:
--I already have all the **n** coordinates of a function acceleration over time in a list, the number is the Acc value and the position in the list is its correspondent time.
--integration is done by adding all the acceleration values one time
--The process of integration has to be repeated **nf** times
--Each time the whole loop is complete, the result should be another list (Frequency) of coordinates, composed by "The integration of the acceleration" and "the frequency value" you did the integration for

So in resume, for every value in range **nf** I need the program to evaluate another function that iterates for **n** values and then repeat the process until the first range is exhausted of course.
Let me show you how that looks like in Fortran:

```
   do k=1, nf                           # this is equivalent to "in range"
      w = 2.d0 * pai * (k-1) * df       # "pai" is pi (3.14...)
      ctemp = 0.d0                      # like when we do ctemp = []
      do i=1,n                          # the other range
         tt = (i - 1) * dt              
         ctemp = ctemp + Acc(i) * exp(-ai * w * tt) * dt      # here there's something similar to append
      end do                                                  
      F(k) = ctemp
   end do
```

Can you help me translate it to python?

Comment: Your code is really confusing. You are not using the numpy array correctly. `w = np.array([])` creates a new numpy array. This also creates one: `w = np.array([2 * np.pi * df * (f - 1)])` and overwrites `w` every time. `tempAcc = [0]` creates an empty Python list. And you are using Numpy to append to it: `np.append(tempAcc`, that might work, but is usually not done.

Comment: I can tell you what to do, learn about Numpy and Python lists. These are not really "bad coding habits" as you call it. It shows that you need to learn more about how it actually works. https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/index.html

Comment: From simple to complex: Try to use pure Python first. No Numpy arrays. Create one empty Python list and append the results to it.

Comment: You're welcome. Please close or modify the question.